# How I can create repeater field in Symfony Easy Admin Bundle

Tags: symfony, easyadmin

I'm created array json field with use symfony console make:entity, but I don't understand how I can add text and textarea field in this, becose I get only one text field in item

I'm created config file but it's not work
easy_admin:
form:
fields:
- { property: 'name', type: 'text', label: 'Name' }
- { property: 'description', type: 'textarea', label: 'Description' }

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

you can add the fields manually on your crudController like this:

```
public function configureFields(string $pageName): iterable
{
    return [
        IdField::new('id')->hideOnForm(),
        TextField::new('name'),
        TextEditorField::new('description'),
    ];
}
```